# Ranorex 8.3.0, When trying to create new recording it doesn't show option to select web ,desktop or mobile application

Tags: testing, automation, ui-automation, ranorex

I Just installed Ranorex studio trial version 8.3.0. While I was going through tutorial trying to learn it, I encountered a problem. After creating new solution when I try to record test, it's just start recording. It doesn't give option to select run an application or open a browser to provide specific path or URL.

I have tried a lot but it's the same way. As I have seen in many tutorials when you click on record it asks you to choose one of these. Is something changed in new release?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is part of the new release of Ranorex 8.3.0. Ranorex has made some changes to Ranorex Recorder and now it no longer asks to select the application you want to test. I think the workaround would be that you can leave your application open before recording and also add the application to the white-list so that when it runs the test it can only focus on the white-listed application and hence would increase efficiency.

More information can be found here https://www.ranorex.com/what-is-new/ under "Ranorex Recorder Improvements" or in the "Release Notes" https://www.ranorex.com/release-notes/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the info. It's pretty hard to do it this way. As you have to leave application open to record. and give path to application manually in actions!